# How do I su to user login shell directly

Tags: bash, shell, su

I do the following many times a day

> I login to a server via ssh as `user1`,
>   I then do `su -` to become `root`,
>   then I do `su --login user2` to become `user2`

Is there a way to tell `su` to go to `user2` directly from `user1`?

**Note:**
`user2`<sup>**1**</sup> does not have a password.  `user2` is named different at different times. (apache, liferay, solr, ftp, ...)

**Note2:**
`user1` is not trusted with `sudo` it's a general purpose account used mainly to access logs. It doesn't even have a password, access granted only with a sshkey only.

**Note3:**
NO solutions that means *any* modification of the remote computer allowed.  I have 30+ servers that I admin.

<sup>**1**</sup> If you are curious it's the user an application runs as (tomcat, apache, jetty or similar)

Comment: Try `su - -c "su - user2"`

Comment: @Keith - You should post that as an answer as it is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
su -c "su - user2"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use 'sudo' instead of 'su'.

Allow user1 to run the shell command (/bin/bash?) as user2 (in the sudoers file - edit with `visudo`):

```
user1 ALL=user2 /bin/bash
```

Then you can (as user1) do:

```
$ sudo -u user2 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that sudo isn't an option. `user1` is a user many people have access to (it's used to inspect logs mostly). I don't want them to have access to `user2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can perform:

```
sudo su user2
```

All you're doing is moving to root to have the privilege to access that account, you can skip a step but will still need to provide root credentials.